# Tab spaces in textarea issue

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Here's my code for my simple CRUD site:

```
<textarea id="bb" class="form-control"name="text" placeholder="Edit this question, <?= $_SESSION['name'] ?>?"> <?= $text ?> </textarea>
```

But the problem is that the textarea has 2 tab spaces at the beginning of the text and after the text there is a space with a tab space next to it.

I'm very sure that the text is trimmed in the MySQLi database. I'm using Bootstrap BTW.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `space`s inside the tag. `<textarea ...><?= $text ?></textarea>`

Comment: why dont you use trim function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove space between `<textarea></textarea>`

```
<textarea id="bb" class="form-control"name="text" placeholder="Edit this question, <?= $_SESSION['name'] ?>?"><?= $text ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought that would be the problem, thanks. Solved

Comment: Welcome :) if it solved your problem then mark it your answer